# .bat file can't escape character

Tags: batch-file

i have a problem in my script:

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd C:\Users\Oskars.Abuhovs\Desktop\testJstoReplace
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s') do (
  set newFile=C:\Users\Oskars.Abuhovs\Desktop\tempjs\%%a
  if exist !newfile! del /f /q !newfile!
  for /f "delims=" %%L in (%%a) do (
    set newLine=%%L
    echo !^newLine:dojo/i18n=ggggggggg^^!dddd! >> !newFile!
  )
)
popd
pause
```

The problem is in a row:

```
echo !^newLine:dojo/i18n=ggggggggg^^!dddd! >> !newFile!
```

Where character ! is not escaped, i read that in `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` ! character should be escaped using `^^`, but it is not happening. How can i escape this character?

**Edited:**

I want to replace part of the string in files. This particular string `dojo/i18n` should be replaced with another string, that contains !. For example `dojo/i18n!mycomputer`.

Whole script together reads files from folder, then search every file line by line searching for this string: `dojo/i18n`, when it is found, string should replace that with early mentioned text `dojo/i18n!mycomputer`, that contains !. I tried to do it with escaping ! character with two ^^ as it is supposed to work when `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, but this combination: ^^! does not work in this line, but when i tried simple `echo ^^!` it worked.

So i am asking how to escape ! character in that line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should the line do? You want replace part of the string, and what is `dddd!` ?  Please explain more.

Comment: @Oskars Abuhovs It's not possible to use `!` in the search nor in the replace string when the variable is expanded by `!` itself. The same is true when you use `%` in a percent expansion.

Comment: @jeb Thanks for your response, i will keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, but in the end i decided to switch to `.vbs` for solving my problem.

Used this code, if someone latter need it:

```
Const ForReading = 1    
Const ForWriting = 2

strFilePath = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOldText = Wscript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = Wscript.Arguments(2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFilePath)
Wscript.Echo objFolder.Path
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each testFile in colFiles
    FileToReplace = strFilePath + testFile.Name
    Wscript.Echo FileToReplace
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileToReplace, ForReading)
    strText = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close

If InStr(strText, strOldText) Then
    strText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileToReplace, ForWriting)
    objFile.Write strText  'WriteLine adds extra CR/LF
    objFile.Close
End If
    strText = ""
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "C:\Users\Oskars.Abuhovs\Desktop\testJstoReplace"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s') do (
  set "newFile=C:\Users\Oskars.Abuhovs\Desktop\tempjs\%%~a"
  if exist "!newfile!" del /f /q "!newfile!"
  for /f "delims=" %%L in ("%%~a") do call:doline "%%~L" "!newfile!"
)
popd
PAUSE
goto:eof

:doline
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "newLine=%~1"
echo %newLine:dojo/i18n=ggggggggg!dddd% >> "%~2"
ENDLOCAL
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code to avoid the need for delayed expansion:

```
@echo on
pushd C:\Users\Oskars.Abuhovs\Desktop\testJstoReplace
set newFile=C:\Users\Oskars.Abuhovs\Desktop\tempjs
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s') do (
  if exist "%newfile%\%%a" del /f /q "%newfile%\%%a"
  for /f "delims=" %%L in ('type "%%a" ') do (
    >>"%newfile%\%%a" echo %%L:dojo/i18n=ggggggggg!dddd
  )
)
popd
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET dddd=replacement^^!data
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s *.doj') do (
  set newFile=u:\temp\%%a
  if exist !newfile! del /f /q !newfile!
  (
  for /f "delims=" %%L in (%%a) do (
    set newLine=%%L
    FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%Q IN ('set dddd') DO (
     SETLOCAL disabledelayedexpansion
     CALL echo %%newLine:dojo/i18n=ggggggggg%%R%%
     endlocal
    )
  )
  )>>!newfile!
)
```

This worked for me. Filenames and masks changed to protect the innocent, naturally.